# How can I proved, that $\left\{\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{\pi}}\sin(kx):k\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,\pi]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series, orthonormal

I want to prove that $S = \left\{\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{\pi}}\sin(kx):k\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ forms an orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,\pi]$. I may use the fact, that $B = \left\{\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{\pi}}\sin(2kx):k\in\mathbb{N}\right\} \cup \left\{\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{\pi}}\cos(2kx):k\in\mathbb{N}\right\} \cup \{ \tfrac 1 \pi \}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2[0,\pi]$.

To show, that $S$ is an orthonormal system is easy. But I have problems to show, that the span of $S$ is dense in $L^2[0,\pi]$.

I could already show that $\left\|\tfrac1\pi\right\|^2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|\langle\tfrac 1\pi,\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{\pi}}\sin(kx)\rangle\right|^2$. Does this imply that $\tfrac1\pi$ is in the closure of the span of $S$?

So am I right that the only think left to show for me is $\left\|\cos(2mx)\right\|^2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|\langle\cos(2mx),\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{\pi}}\sin(kx)\rangle\right|^2$? (which I couldn't do so far) My idea is to prove that $B$ is in the closure of the span of S and thus the span of $S$ dense in $L^2[0,\pi]$ (because the span of $B$ is dense in $L^2[0,\pi]$).

Comment: If you can prove that $B$ is an orthonormal basis, then it follows automatically that $S$ is an orthonormal set. On the span and density: I am not sure to have correctly understood what you mean, because in the title you state that $S$ is an orthonormal basis. In any case, the formula for the norm of $\cos(2mx)$ is not correct as the r.h.s. is identically=0.

Comment: The integral $\int_0^\pi \cos(2mx)\sin(kx) dx$ of the r.h.s is for $k\ne m$ equal to $\frac{k \left(- \cos\left(\pi k\right) + 1\right)}{k^{2} - 4 m^{
2}}$ and therefore just zero, iff k is even.

Comment: Another method: Find a basis, $W$, similar to your $B$, of $L_2[-\pi,\pi]$. Given $f\in L_2[0,\pi]$, let $g$ be the odd extension of $f$ to $[-\pi,\pi]$. Write $g$ in terms of the basis $W$. Then show the constant and $\cos$ terms of this representation vanish. From this, deduce that $f$ can be written in terms of the elements of $S$.

Comment: @Avitus: just have rewritten my question. So it might be more clearly stated now ;-)

Comment: @tampis thanks, now I begin to understand :) First of all I missed the absence of "2" in the $\sin$ computation of the norm of of $\cos(2mx)$: your remark is right. Secondly, I think that the trick is the following: as you consider L^2 functions on $[0,\pi]$ you do not consider any symmetry on the elements of the space. In other words, you can expand any element $f$ of such space in $\sin(kx)$ expansions as the periodic extensions of $f$ can be either odd or even, in general. Choosing a $\sin(kx)$ expansion means that we consider the odd periodic extension. Your method makes sense to me

Comment: @David: Your idea seems to me much more elegant than mine. If you copy your comment into an answer, I will except it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, $$\begin{equation}\lVert f\rVert^2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \Bigl\lvert\langle f,\, \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sin (kx)\rangle\Bigr\rvert^2\end{equation}$$ proves that $f$ is in the closure of the span of $S$. You can write $f = f_S + (f - f_S)$, where $f_S$ is the orthogonal projection onto the closure of the span of $S$. Then

$$\lVert f\rVert^2 = \lVert f_S\rVert^2 + \lVert f - f_S\rVert^2,\text{ and } f_S = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \langle f,\, \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sin (kx)\rangle\cdot  \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sin (kx)$$

(modulo possibly conjugating/swapping the order of the factors in the inner product if you consider complex-valued functions). So if you have the first equation, you know that $\lVert f - f_S \rVert = 0$, or $f = f_S$.

Comment: Sorry if the question seems stupid, but where does 
$$\lVert f\rVert^2 = \lVert f_S\rVert^2 + \lVert f - f_S\rVert^2$$
come from? For this, shouldn't $$\Re(\langle f_S , f-f_S \rangle)=0 \, ?$$
Why is that?